# Является ли введенное число любой разрядности палиндромом? с использованием цикла

Tags: c++

Код рабочий, но нечитабельный. Как его упростить.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void main() {
    int num;
    cin >> num;
    int roz = 1;
    int res = num;

    while( res / 10 ) {
        ++roz;
        res = res / 10;
    }

    int left = 0;
    int right = 0;
    bool answer = false;

    for( int i = roz; i >= 1; i-- ) {
        for( int j = -roz; j < 0; j++ ) {
            left = int( num / pow( 10, i - 1 ) ) % 10;
            right = int( num / pow( 10, roz + j ) ) % 10;
            cout << left << " || " << right << endl;

            if( left == right ) {
                i--;
                answer = true;
                continue;
            }
            else {
                answer = false;
            }

            i = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    answer ? ( cout << "yes" ) : ( cout << "no\n" );
}
```

Comment: Код не только не читаемый (поправил форматирование), но и не компилируемый: 1) `void main()` 2) забыт либо `<math.h>`, либо `<cmath>`. **P.S.** А обязательно работать именно с числом? Раз уж оно вводится, то вводится как строка, а обнаружение палиндрома в строке намного проще.

Comment: Впрочем, и с числом алгоритм тоже укладывается в пару-другую строк,  безо всяких `pow()` и вложенных циклов,  :)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Коли уж число приходит из `stdin`, то прикинемся ленивыми и обработаем его как строку:

```
int is_palindrome( const char *s, size_t length )
{
    size_t i = 0, j = length ? length : strlen( s );
    // Требуемый цикл:
    while( i <= j ) {
        if( s[i++] != s[--j] ) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int is_palindrome( const string &s )
{
    return is_palindrome( s.c_str(), s.size() );
}
```

Но если попался преподаватель без чувства юмора, или число приходит действительно как число... Просто развернём исходное число *поразрядно* задом наперёд и посмотрим на результат. Получилось то же самое число - ура, палиндром:

```
int is_palindrome( unsigned long n )
{
    unsigned long m = n;
    unsigned long flip = 0;
    // Требуемый цикл:
    while( m > 0 ) {
        flip *= 10;
        flip += m % 10;
        m /= 10;
    }
    return flip == n;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Немного оптимизированный вариант соседнего ответа (меньше шагов цикла почти в два раза)

```
int is_palindrome(unsigned long n1){
    unsigned long n2 = 0;
    if (!(n1 % 10)) return 0;
    while (n2 < n1) {
        n2 *= 10;
        n2 += n1 % 10;
        n1 /= 10;
    }
    // Идея заключается в том, что для палиндромов с четным количеством 
    // цифр работает условие n2 == n1.
    // При нечетном количестве цифр у числа n2 будет на одну цифру больше
    // (поскольку цикл завершается при n2 >= n1) причем эта 
    // цифра - младший разряд. Поскольку она на результат не влияет, мы 
    // избавляемся от нее путем целочисленного деления на 10
    return n2 == n1 || n2 / 10 == n1;
}
```

См. [примеры](http://ideone.com/YaQlud)

Comment: Вроде не срабатывает на `11000`

Comment: @VladD Буду думать :)

Comment: А так же 10, 100, 1000...

Comment: @tutankhamun: По идее, если число оканчивается на 0 (но не равно 0), то это гарантировано _не_ палиндром.

Comment: @VladD Пожалуй все зависит от условий задачи. Пожалуй добавлю условие в ответ, но учитывая невозможность записи в числовую переменную фиксированного количества нулей слева, я бы считал 11000 палиндромом

Comment: @tutankhamun: Угу, вопрос интерпретации условия (считать ли ведущие нули валидными).

Comment: @VladD Вот еще бы кто подсказал хоть один случай применения этой задачи на практике (вне рамок уроков информатики)

Comment: @tutankhamun, насколько понимаю, вопрос о практической применимости чего-либо в математике - очень туманный :-)